# Azure Pipelines & Nuget Packages - Set pack version to tag version

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I managed to have my pipeline triggered when I push a tag to the repo. The tag is always is the format "v(Major).(Minor).(Release)(-alpha)".

How can I get that information from the tag and set is as the package version?

**EDIT 1:**
The command `git tag -a 1.0.1` will create the tag that will trigger the pipeline and I want the nugget package version to be "1.0.1" like the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to do some parsing and error handling so this runs for just tags, but you can source and parse the value from `Build.SourceBranch` variable as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables):

> The branch of the triggering repo the build was queued for. Some
> examples:
>
> - Git repo branch: refs/heads/master
> - Git repo pull request: refs/pull/1/merge
> - TFVC repo branch: $/teamproject/main
> - TFVC repo gated check-in: Gated_2016-06-06_05.20.51.4369;username@live.com
> - TFVC repo shelveset build: myshelveset;username@live.com
> - **When your pipeline is triggered by a tag: refs/tags/your-tag-name**
>
> When you use this variable in your build number format, the forward
> slash characters (/) are replaced with underscore characters _).
>
> Note: In TFVC, if you are running a gated check-in build or manually
> building a shelveset, you cannot use this variable in your build
> number format.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without doing parsing and error handling with the following YAML:

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - 0.*
    - 1.*
    - 2.*
    - 3.*
    - 4.*
    - 5.*
    - 6.*
    - 7.*
    - 8.*
    - 9.*

pool: 'LocalWindows'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
   
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/Source/*.vbproj'
    versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
    versionEnvVar: 'BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME'
    includeSymbols: true
```

The special thing is, that you must have a trigger which only listens on tags and then you can use the envvar BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME.

You can adjust the tag-includes as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the pipeline, you have an option called tag format, where you can see the package version.

Please take a look at the below screenshot :

[image: Pipelines Tag Format]

[image: Artifact]

Comment: I'm sorry Monika, you don't seem to have got the idea here... please check EDIT 1 for further details

Comment: @Leonardo - Sorry to have missed your comment earlier. I see that Matt has answered the question.